# Make __has_include portable in C

Tags: c, include

`__has_include` is included in the C++ standard since C++17. However, in C, is just supported by compilers that implement it as an extension. As far as I am aware, just [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005finclude.html) and [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#has-include) support it. Is there a way I can accomplish a similar effect portably in C? [MSVC](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0061r1.html) just seems to support it for C++.